# AWS: No Key Pairs Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been given a key called `Access.pem` and I am trying to launch an AWS instance.
In Step 7: Review Instance Launch, when I attempt to launch the instance I get the following error:

```
No keys pairs found.
You don't have any key pairs. Please create a new key pair by selecting the 
Create a new key pair option above to continue.
```

I have attempted to import my key pair with the steps outlined by amazon (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)

This includes:

- Placing `Access.pem` in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- And importing the key via the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/

In the second attempt when browsing for the key, the `Access.pem` key cannot be selected on my Mac. When I copy the contents, I am informed the key is too long.

How can I use this key?

Comment: could you please post the screenshot/logtext of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key-pair is often given to employees by their institution. As such I will assume this is the case. If you have exhausted all other options, I would contact your IT department to make sure they have added you.

Next time you log in (assuming you have been granted access), your company key-pairs should be available.

Answer (score 0):

basically when we launch an instance there is option to create a new key pair, and after downloading the key pair save option marked as checked we can proceed to launch an instance. we can create a key pair from key pairs section from before. If you are sure that you have created a key pair as you mentioned "Access.pem" then be sure in which region you have created the key pair. If you create a key pair in the regin "us-east-1-a North Virginia" and if you try to launch an instance in other region like "us-east-2-a -Ohio" in this case you will not find the key pair. when launchin an ec2-instance or any other service that needs key pairs will not suggest the key pair (when the region is changed), check this things.

and while doing ssh from terminal if it is windows/mac/linux be sure you have set the permission of the pem file as 400. using like this "chmod 400 Access.pem"